# White right and left margins in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This issue has been bothering me forever. I'm using the Bootstrap framework and whenever I view my site on mobile devices I get 20px margins on the right and left side of the navbar.

In the past some have suggested the following:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It solves the issue with the navbar margins but creates issues with the rest of the page.

You can view an example of this problem here: http://www.theplaybook.co

Any insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by this line (in `bootstrap-responsive.css`, line 802):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
```